# How to get js-cookies?

Tags: reactjs, cookies, redux, font-awesome, js-cookie

I used redux and I want to fetch my API using the cookies item like this:

```
import cookies from "js-cookies";

api/get_liste/${cookies.getItem("moncentre")}
```

when I run my app, `${cookies.getItem("moncentre")}` is `null`.

My codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-rubin-tf56r?file=/src/App.js:157-212

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Does `moncentre` associate with fontawesome?

Comment: No @SMAKSS it's not associate with fontawesome

Comment: So getting `null` from that cookie is nothing about the warning you getting. How are you setting that cookie?

Comment: @SMAKSS I use the cookies  like in the post

Comment: @SMAKSS can you check please https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-rubin-tf56r?file=/src/App.js:157-212

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem here is, **you never set a cookie in your app and then try to get the cookie that never exists so it will return `null`** since there is no value for it in the browser cookies.

In order to set a cookie, you should do this (according to the [package provider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookies)):

```js
cookies.setItem('_code_sandbox_key', 'Cookie did set.')
```

The other thing that you facing is the warning that you get in your dev tools, so according to [this doc](https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site), **this console warning is not an error or an actual problem — Chrome is just spreading the word about this new standard to increase developer adoption**. To fix this you should add `SameSite="none Secure"` (and then clear all your cookies with the dev tool) to let the browser know the script is not related to your site and that it is a third-party library that you are using.

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js" SameSite="none Secure"></script>
```

**NOTE:** You can follow this [thread](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/15643) for more information.

Comment: thank you, but how can I get cookie for another domain ?

Comment: @CodeLover Actually due to [same-origin-policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), you can't read or set a cookie from another domain.